# Posting data to another application in request body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core

It might not be the best solution but the requirement is to post some data in the request body to another application, so that the data can be read by the receiving application and perform operations depending on the data posted. I would like to post the data from a.mydomain.com/PostData to b.mydomain.com/RequestData where RequestData has a return type of IACtionResult which renders a view on application B depending on the data being posted. Is this possible. Any help is greatly appreciated

I have created a web request and used the GetRequestStream() to create the body, after the body is created I would like to redirect to  b.mydomain.com/RequestData where i can read the request body and render my view

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://b.mydomain.com/RequestData");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;`enter code here`

            // Get the request stream.  
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.  
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.  
            dataStream.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `redirect to b.mydomain.com/RequestData`? What do you want to do with response from appilcation B?

Comment: @TaoZhou The idea is to read the information from the http body posted by Application A in application B, and process it depending on what type of data is posted by Application A. It is more like getting the data from a query string, but the requirement specifically states that the data cannot be on a query string, So we are trying to post the data in the body instead and since the both App A and App B are on the same domain, trying to get the info out of the http body. Any other solutions would also be a great help. Thank you a lot